# Binding MPI processes on the second CPU socket with MVAPICH2.2

Tags: mpi, numa, mvapich2

I'm using NUMA compute nodes where the network (*Mellanox InfiniBand HCA*) is connected to the second CPU socket (and NUMA node). 
Is there any environment variable to simply bind all MPI processes to the second CPU socket with **MVAPICH2.2**?

The `MV2_CPU_BINDING_LEVEL=socket MV2_CPU_BINDING_POLICY=bunch` combination does not work since it starts regrouping processes
on the first CPU socket.

I usually end up using something like: 
`-genv MV2_CPU_MAPPING 10:11:12:13:14:15:16:17:18:19:30:31:32:33:34:35:36:37:38:39`  *(use all SMTs of the second 10-core CPU socket)* but this is ugly and dependant on the amount of cores.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an environment variable, but if you're able to modify `/etc/default/grub` on your systems, then you can isolate the cores on package 0 from the scheduler.  Example for your 10-core (hyper threading) CPUs:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="$GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT isolcpus=0-19"
```

Comment: The idea is interesting but a bit too extreme. Some other people would want to use all available cores with other apps.

Comment: I had the exact same problem a year ago, trying to keep MPI on the package with the IB adapter to avoid the QPI link.  My team was doing fine grained latency measurements.  Unfortunately the only solution I found was the above, despite all my research into shielding.  I’ve favorited the question, and I hope you find a better answer.